# Trying to display images from associated table in Grails

Tags: html, database, amazon-web-services, grails, dns

I have two tables: Hotel and Content

The Content domain looks like this, hotelId is being generated:

```
class Content {

Hotel hotel
String featuredImageUrl

static constraints = {
    featuredImageUrl nullable:true
}
```

I am uploading images to S3 from the Hotel's show page to the related Content table, this is working - now I want to display these images.

I thought something like this would work, it is not:

```
 <g:if test="${content.featuredImageUrl}">
   <img src="${content.featuredImageUrl}" />
 </g:if>
```

Comment: Does it not work? I don't see what your question is.

Comment: No it doesn't work. My question is, how do I display the images?

Comment: What is the content of the property `featuredImageUrl` and can you just try loading that directly? Is your S3 bucket have permissions set to serve these images?

Comment: featuredImageUrl is a the url to the image on S3. Permissions and policies are all good. It's just the correct bit of code I need to get the images displaying. When I run the code from above I get a 'Cannot get property 'featuredImageUrl' on null object' error.

Comment: You need to provide those details in your question. Show us how you are passing the content object to your gsp from your controller.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the info I gave was enough. I'm not passing my content object to my gsp from the controller, perhaps that's where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When rendering content in a GSP you need to provide the object to render, grails has no way of knowing which Content you're asking for - you have to provide it.

Example:

```
class SomeController {
    def index() {
        // Get the object/objects from your db somehow:
        def content = Content.get(1)

        // render your view with the given model/objects
        // by default grails-app/views/controllername/actionname.gsp
        render [content: content]
    }
 }
```

See Docs - 8.1.3 Models and Views in http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html

Comment: Hi, I fiddled around with your solution and couldn't get it to work. You are right that I didn't articulate my question well. Let me rephrase incase you misunderstood. I want to display the images from my content table to the show page of the related hotel object (where the id of hotel = hotelId from content).

Comment: Am I on the right track with this? ----    def showContent() 
    {
        def content = Content.findByHotelId( params.id )
        render [content: content]
    }

Comment: Please provide an error or issue along with what you've tried. Maybe upload a full example to github with a failing test would be easier to debug.

Comment: This is in my 'hotel.gsp ------             <g:if test="${content.hotelId}" action="showContent">

                <img src = "${content.featuredImageUrl}" />
            </g:if>


ERROR: 'Cannot get property 'hotelId' on null object'